# Sample index doesn't work with frame number

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

I want to generate layers of spheres connected between each other dynamically (just like an artificial neural network), my approach used simulation nodes and sample indices, which have worked manually and individually, but not when trying to automate the connection generation via frame number, here's a video showing it:
https://youtu.be/AtJtNo8nSDI

Blender file:

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: The audio in your link  can't be heard, anyway.. Please sketch out in words or pictures, (e.g.) a few key moments in the evolution of your system, so we can tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually when I download your file, what I see is even if I make a manual connection (which you say works) by simply setting the second to a static index number instead of changing it dynamically, the connection just appears on the first frame (although the indices for the connection don't change and should stay the whole time). So what the problem here seems to be is that the mesh line is just generated on the first frame and not refreshed over the course of the animation. Which would explain why there is no new connection to each index given by the frame number.

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering why you needed a simulation for this - in case you do though for some reason, this answer might not help you.

But: as far as I can see you only want the end point of a mesh line change towards the location of a sphere given by its index. And this index should change with the frame number. So just throw out all that simulation stuff and connect it directly.

[image: network without simulation]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

your simulation would work, if you are using this node tree:

[image]

[image]

The reason why yours isn't working is because there is no connection between your output and your input node of the zone. So the input is basically thrown away every frame and replaced by your mesh line. But you want that to be added. This is done by the join geometry node.

Comment: My answer is a bit different - I actually did not realize the goal was that an established connection should persist, I thought it should change on each frame. So I simply threw out all that simulation stuff :D